# Postmates API mismatched_price_quote error

Tags: shopify-app, postmates

We keep getting an error as followed when attempting to dispatch deliveries:

> mismatched_price_quote: 'The price quote specified doesn't match the
>   delivery.' ({'kind': 'error', 'code': 'mismatched_price_quote',
>   'message': "The price quote specified doesn't match the delivery."})
>   [APIException]

We've checked the logs and the delivery estimate matches that at the time of attempted Postmates delivery dispatch.  If the prices match why the price match error?

Postmates API doesn't document this returned error.

Comment: This error could also refer to delivery quote vs delivery attempt differences.  

In comparing the data the only difference was that the address during the quote used California vs at the time of delivery attempt creation the state was "CA".  

In testing directly with the API we tried creating a delivery quote and delivery attempt using a State mismatch like this and there were no issues.  The delivery was created.

Comment: the delivery quote is only available for 5 minutes, so if you try to create delivery with expired delivery quote id then also you will get this error

Comment: @Vishal prices match as well as quote hadn't expired.  Turns out this is a general error message for a number of reasons....only way to get more info is to contact Postmates tech support.... lousy.

Comment: Its also very difficult to contact postmates tech support :(